# obfuscate json from webserver

Tags: json, encryption, obfuscation

I've got an android and iphone app that both get the required data from a webserver. The data is sent via json to the client. Using this setup other people might simply retrieve the url the app is calling and this way could make use of the data that I gather with my scripts on the server. To make it short: I don't want that :)

My idea is to make the json unreadable for example by encrypting it. This would make it a little harder to retrieve the information since this way some who would like to use my service would had to decompile the app an lookup any decryption stuff I had implemented.

Therefore two questions:

1. Do there exist some libraries that already offer such a functionality (Server side is Java)?
2. Does anyone of you have any other suggestions how I could protect my api from unwanted guests?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can't you just `Authenticate` & `Authorize` the calling user?

Comment: Yeah, this is a good idea, however this way I would have to make each user register himself and I want to prevent the user from experience this unnecessary annoyance. Or is my thinking wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the options available would be...

1. to lock down the API to `Authorized/Authenticated` users.
2. Using [`BSON`](http://bsonspec.org/) to obfuscate the data.

You could always use `oAuth` to allow the users to authenticate based on an account they already have: **Facebook**, **Twitter**, **Google** etc.